# Can a soulknife with quickdraw use iaijutsu focus?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

A soulknife of 5th level can create a mindblade as a free action.

Iaijutsu focus requires you to draw your weapon to deal extra damage.

Could I, for example, create a mindblade inside a sheathe then draw it with quickdraw to use iaijutsu focus? Or am I overcomplicating things and simply creating the blade is considered drawing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The [soulknife](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/soulknife.htm)'s special ability [free draw](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/soulknife.htm#freeDraw) isn't [drawing a weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#draworSheatheaWeapon)...

The [soulknife](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/soulknife.htm)'s supernatural ability [free draw](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/soulknife.htm#freeDraw) says

> At 5th level, a soulknife becomes able to materialize his mind blade as a free action instead of a move action. He can make only one attempt to materialize the mind blade per round, however.

The skill Iaijutsu Focus says

> If you attack a flat-footed opponent immediately after drawing a melee weapon, you can deal extra damage, based on the result of an Iaijutsu Focus check. (*Oriental Adventures* 58)

Actions in Combat implies that [drawing a weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#draworSheatheaWeapon) means not generating it spontaneously but taking the weapon out of something.

> Drawing a weapon so that you can use it in combat, or putting it away so that you have a free hand, requires a move action. This action also applies to weapon-like objects carried in easy reach, such as wands.

So to *draw a weapon*, the weapon's removed from its container, even if that's the built-in sheath of the gnome quickrazor (*Races of Stone* 154).

### ...But a soulknife *can* make a fair case about allowing the skill Iaijutsu Focus to work with his mind blade

Because "[t]he moment [the soulknife] relinquishes his grip on his blade, it dissipates," the mind blade's created in the soulknife's hand, so if the soulknife tucks his hand into a sack or whatever, he can *create* the mind blade within the container. Then as a move action, during a normal move if the soulknife has a base attack bonus of at least +1, or as a free action using the feat [Quick Draw](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#quickDraw), he can withdraw the mind blade, therefore possibly benefiting from the cross-class ranks he's invested into the skill Iaijutsu Focus.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I thought it was worth noting anyway: the Iaijutsu Focus skill doesn't actually say that the weapon you attack with, must be the same weapon you drew. For example; one could take his hand off his scythe as a free action, draw a dagger with quickdraw as a free action, drop the dagger as a free action, and put his hand back on his scythe as a free action, then use Iaijutsu Focus with his scythe even though it was already in his hands when the fight started.

Comment: @Axel_690 While totally textually accurate, getting the DM to agree to letting the Iaijutsu Focus skill work that way (without bribery or intimidation) may prove challenging.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I once recieved a little resistance to the idea that i could draw a dagger with quickdraw as a free action, drop it, then apply Iaijutsu Focus to thrown shuriken.

Comment: @Axel_690 If really exploiting, spit fukimi-bari (*AE* 7) (1 gp; 0.1 lbs.).

Comment: That is an excellent idea! I had never thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

**Whether or not materializing a mindblade counts as drawing a weapon is subject to DM interpretation (but the answer will often be Yes).** RAW, Quick Draw only draws a weapon in name only. Nowhere does a Soulknife gain the ability to draw his weapon as if it were an ordinary one, but this could just be an oversight of the class itself and not a restriction of the character. Oriental Adventures and Psionics were developed separately and without each other in mind, so they don't have explicit rules for interactions between them, which leaves the rules subject to the interpretation of the reader. You could justify that materializing and swinging a mindblade could be analogous to drawing a weapon from a sheath with an Iaijutsu strike, but it's ultimately your DM's call as to whether or not you can do this.

Most DMs will rule in your favor - this is the Soulknife after all, they're already fairly weak. Only a particularly picky or resentful DM will say no.